# Why can't I get my textbox to enable/disable with my checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am sure this is any easy question, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

What I am trying to accomplish is when the checkbox is "checked" I want it to enable the textbox.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
    <title> iSCSI Admin v0.1 </title>

    <body>

        <fieldset style="width:640px;">
            <legend>
                Enable textbox
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onclick="enabledisable()">
            </legend>

            <form name="form1">
                Text:
                <input type="text" name="textname" disabled>
            </form>

        </fieldset>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function enabledisable() {

                if (document.checkbox1.checked) {

                    document.form1.textname.disabled=false;

                } else {

                    document.form1.textname.disabled=true;

                }

            }
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you mean `<input type="text" name="textname" disabled>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you fixed the question. You need to put the checkbox in the form.
Try this:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function enabledisable() {
                if (document.form1.checkbox1.checked) {    
                    document.form1.textname.disabled=false;
                } else {
                    document.form1.textname.disabled=true;
                }
            }​
    </script>
    <form name="form1">
        <fieldset style="width:640px;">
            <legend>Enable textbox  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onclick="enabledisable()"></legend>
               Text:
                <input type="text" name="textname" disabled="true" >
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>​​​​
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the `legend` tag.

Comment: Awesome that fixed the problem! So I need to understand something, only forms can contain inputs? As long as the fieldset tag containing the inputs is inside the form tag it will work right?

Comment: no you can put inputs outside of forms but if you want them to submit with the form they won't.. I only put it within the form because it is easy to target that way from javascript. The other answer that uses getElementById is actually a better way of doing this, you just needed to put an id on the checkbox and reference by that value using getElementById.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input id="textname" type="text" />
```

```
function enabledisable() {
    if (document.getElementById("Checkbox1").checked) {
        document.form1.textname.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        document.form1.textname.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would upvote this answer but the original post doesn't have an id on the checkbox..

Comment: Very cool this works perfect, I just had a tiny problem with the capital "C" but other than that perfect!, Thanks.

Comment: I gave an upvote because if I would known about this I would have done it like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  document.form1.textname.disabled='disabled';
  document.form1.textname.disabled='';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nqaJZ/

Answer (score 0):

Note: I added -> id="checkbox1"  to your checkbox field.
Note: I changed the if condition as well -> document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked
Note: I changed your code which enables / disables textfield as well -> document.form1.text.disabled=false;

notice I changed it from targetname (which was not there) to your textfield name which you had was "text.

Hope it helps.

iSCSI Admin v0.1

```
<body>

    <fieldset style="width:640px;">
        <legend>
            Enable textbox
            <input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox1"  name="checkbox1" onclick="enabledisable()">
        </legend>

        <form name="form1">
            Text:
            <input type="text" name="text" disabled>
        </form>

    </fieldset>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function enabledisable() {

            if (document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked) {

                document.form1.text.disabled=false;

            } else {

                document.form1.text.disabled=true;

            }

        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: yeah that typos is what happens when I got a dozen things on my mind. I am also messing with our iSCSI server hence why my mock up here is called "iSCSI Admin" I need to put something there.

Comment: yup typos happens all the time :D agreed.